Failed to install the app on the device, with error code 3002 & 3000, Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError on Xcode 15.3
Failed to install the app on the device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 3002
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-04-12 13:00:55 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    NSURL = "file:///Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dwlcjztonmnjygafwwnxdjtbzkwe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/target.app/";
}
--
Failed to install the app on the device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 3002
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    NSURL = "file:///Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dwlcjztonmnjygafwwnxdjtbzkwe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/target.app/";
}
--
The item at target.app is not a valid bundle.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 3000
Failure Reason: The path to the provided bundle's main executable could not be determined.
Recovery Suggestion: Ensure that your bundle's Info.plist contains a value for the key CFBundleExecutable.
User Info: {
    NSURL = "file:///Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dwlcjztonmnjygafwwnxdjtbzkwe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/target.app/";
    ProvidedBundle = "file:///Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dwlcjztonmnjygafwwnxdjtbzkwe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/target.app/";
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.4.1 (21E236)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.24";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.100.58";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 2486;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3000;
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError.3002.com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 8192;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "par[tag:am_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}

System Information
macOS Version 14.4.1 (Build 23E224)
Xcode 15.3 (22618) (Build 15E204a)
Timestamp: 2024-04-12T18:30:55+05:30
The project is running on the simulator properly with no errors.
But while running on the real device (the iPhone), the build is successful but getting the mentioned issue.
Also, while creating the.ipa file, we are getting the error mentioned below.
enter image description here
We have tried following thing to resolve the issue but nothing is worked.

Clean project and try to run the app on the real device.

Disconnect iPhone from Mac
On iPhone:
Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted Computers
Uninstall the application
Reconnect iPhone to Mac
In Xcode
Window > Devices & Simulators
You should see your device in the left sidebar
Re-pair the device

In the project Target -> Build Settings search for: search for Excluded Architectures add arm64 there.

Change the archive destination directory to a location on the local SSD (and not an external HDD).

Go to settings >> Select Privacy & Security >> Turn developer mode off if on >> Turn developer mode back on an follow instrctions >> The run your app on xcode
`



I faced a similar issue, My project supports multiple languages, and I had localized the CFBundleShortVersionString in the infoPlist.strings files for each language. This caused problems when uploading new builds to my device and simulator.
To resolve this, I removed the localization for CFBundleShortVersionString and moved it to the main Info.plist file instead. Here’s how it should look:
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>

CFBundleShortVersionString should not be localized. Making this change worked for me, and I hope it helps you too!

Restarting my iphone device fixed this issue.

Ajay Prabhakar's solution didn't work exactly, but together with other clues, it provided the right idea. Check your email from your last upload. Did you see a message from Apple indicating problems with the build?
For me, I had an email with the content:
Although delivery was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next delivery. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
ITMS-90784: Missing bundle name - The CFBundleName and CFBundleDisplayName Info.plist keys are missing or have empty values in the bundle with the com.MyCompanyName.AppName bundle ID. Please provide at least one of the values and upload a new build. If your app supports multiple locales, ensure that you’ve provided a value for at least one of these keys in the Info.plist file in addition to your app’s localization folders. For details, view:
I resolved the issue not by adding an Info.plist key, but by creating a strings file that localized the name into the different locales, which let it appear on the home screen with names specific to each locale/language. For example, I created InfoPlist.strings inside the Xcode project folder, then localized the file (by checking the language box in the right sidebar panel) into the other languages in which my app is localized, and input
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Home Screen Name";

(input your own name in the locale on the right side of the equation line)
Rebuilt and the app appeared fine. Other apps didn't have this problem because they either weren't localized, or were being tested on devices that weren't in this target language. It happens for devices that meet one of the languages in which your app is localized, but doesn't have a home screen title/bundleName localized.  FYI, Error: 3002.
